# how to start the linux tomcat on nohup mode on jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I used below command in jenkins, After execute this command, It shows that tomcat is started but tomcat is not started

#!/bin/bash

TOMCAT_HOME=/home/apache-tomcat

nohup $TOMCAT_HOME/bin/startup.sh &

I need run tomcat in nohup mode on linux machine with Jenkins

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat is being killed by the Jenkins ProcessTreeKiller:

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/ProcessTreeKiller.html

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28388684/keeping-a-build-process-running-after-jenkins-job

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by "nohup mode". Starting a service directly from the shell like this is always a bad idea. Use a [systemd unit file](https://gist.github.com/drmalex07/e6e99dad070a78d5dab24ff3ae032ed1) or [Sysv Init script.](https://gist.github.com/miglen/5590986)